# Changing the order of an array based on another with javascript sort

Tags: javascript, typescript

I have two arrays,

```
A = [green, blue, red];

B = [2, 1, 0]
```

I want to change the order of **A** to be in [red, blue, green]. The changes are  based on the value of **B**
Below is what I have tried,

```
arrangeValues();
function arrangeValues() {
    A.sort((a,b)=>{
        let orderA:any=B.indexOf(a.value);
        let orderB:any=B.indexOf(b.value);
        if (orderA==-1)
            orderA=99999;
        if (orderB==-1)
            orderB=99999;
        return orderB-orderA
    })
}
```

Comment: The order of b doesn't make sense with the expected output, that would be [red,blue,green]

Comment: Is `B` always the same length as `A` and made up of consecutive numbers starting at 0?

Comment: 2 in B refers to green, so greens index should be 2

Comment: Yes both values should have equal length

Comment: Then you'll need to specify -- see the answer below, right now we can't tell what you want exactly

Comment: @bambam I ve edited my question

Comment: wow, I like map.

Comment: What result do you expect for `1, 2, 0`?

Comment: [red, green, blue]

Comment: @saila - You'll want to double-check my logic then. The code in my answer does that, but it's (embarrassingly) not what I *meant* to do, and I can't guarantee it handles every sequence correctly. I've updated the answer to show all six possible sequences.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> I want to change the order of A to be in [red, blue, green]

The simplest way is to create a new array, using the indexes from `B`, and taking values from `A` based on where you are in `B`:

```js
const A = ["green", "blue", "red"];
const B = [2, 1, 0];
const result = [];
B.forEach((entry, index) => {
  result[entry] = A[index];
});
console.log(result);
```

Just to be sure that really does what you want (because it was actually a typo on my part, I meant to do something different but seem to have accidentally done what you wanted), here are all six combinations:

```js
const A = ["green", "blue", "red"];

function test(B) {
  const result = [];
  B.forEach((entry, index) => {
    result[entry] = A[index];
  });
  console.log(B.join(", "), "=>", result.join(", "));
}
for (let i = 0; i < A.length; ++i) {
  for (let j = 0; j < A.length; ++j) {
    if (j != i) {
      for (let k = 0; k < A.length; ++k) {
        if (i != k && j != k) {
          test([i, j, k]);
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper {
  max-height: 100% !important;
}
```

Here's are all six doing what I *meant* to do (which is [what zvona did](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51224265/157247), zvona's is cleaner):

```js
const A = ["green", "blue", "red"];

function test(B) {
  const result = [];
  B.forEach((entry, index) => {
    result[index] = A[entry];
  });
  console.log(B.join(", "), "=>", result.join(", "));
}
for (let i = 0; i < A.length; ++i) {
  for (let j = 0; j < A.length; ++j) {
    if (j != i) {
      for (let k = 0; k < A.length; ++k) {
        if (i != k && j != k) {
          test([i, j, k]);
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper {
  max-height: 100% !important;
}
```

Comment: @ T.J what is ab

Comment: @saila - It's a joke: "abuse" vs. "use".

Answer (score 1):

You can do that using a simple for loop
something like:

```
function arrangeValues(A,B) {
  var sorted = [];
  for(var i=0;i<A.length;i++){
      sorted.push(A[B[i]]);
  }
  return sorted;
}
```

Here is a live example:

```js
function arrangeValues(A,B) {
  var sorted = [];
  for(var i=0;i<A.length;i++){
      sorted.push(A[B[i]]);
  }
  return sorted;
}

var A = ["green", "blue", "red"];
var B = [2, 1, 0];
var result = arrangeValues(A,B);
console.log(result);
```

Answer (score 1):

Simple way:

```
const A: Array<string> = ["green", "blue", "red"];
const B: Array<number> = [2, 1, 0];
const result: Array<string> = B.map((entry: number) => A[entry]);
```

Live Example:

```js
const A = ["green", "blue", "red"];
const B = [2, 1, 0];
const result = B.map((entry) => A[entry]);
console.log(result);
```

All six combinations using this approach:

```js
const A = ["green", "blue", "red"];
function test(B) {
  const result = B.map((entry) => A[entry]);
  console.log(B.join(", "), "=>", result.join(", "));
}
for (let i = 0; i < A.length; ++i) {
  for (let j = 0; j < A.length; ++j) {
    if (j != i) {
      for (let k = 0; k < A.length; ++k) {
        if (i != k && j != k) {
          test([i, j, k]);
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: If the original approach of sorting `A` based on the corresponding `B` was correct – and the comment “2 in B refers to green, so greens index should be 2” suggests it was – this won’t do the same thing in general. `[1, 2, 0]` is blue-red-green if it’s a sequence of indexes to read and red-green-blue if it’s the target index for a given element, for example.

Comment: @saila: You should try them out on different arrays first, because they don’t do the same thing.

Answer (score 0):

Map the corresponding colors from `A` to values from `B` by index and sort by them:

```
const A = ['green', 'blue', 'red'];

const B = [2, 1, 0];

const sorted = A.sort((a,b) => {

    const [aV,bV] = [a,b].map((_,i) => B[i]);

    return aV - bV;

})

console.log(sorted);
```

Or if we can assume that `B` contains indexes, then a simple `map` would do the job:

```
const A = ['green', 'blue', 'red'];

const B = [2, 1, 0];

const result = B.map(i => A[i]);

console.log(result);
```